# Spring: encrypted password configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm getting this error message when I'm starting my springboot:

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 23, column 9:
            trust-store: file:keystore.jks
            ^
expected <block end>, but found Scalar
 in 'reader', line 24, column 37:
            key-store-password: {cipher}0b544ca0afbcd904c687d902d95b4db4 ...
```

My `bootstrap.yml` is:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: tdev-wssc-configserver

  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      host: ${vault_server_host:localhost}
      port: ${vault_server_port:8200}
      scheme: ${vault_server_scheme:https}
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      fail-fast: true
      config:
        order: -10
      ssl:
        trust-store: file:keystore.jks
        trust-store-password: {cipher}0b544ca0afbcd904c687d902d95b4db415f6309cbae49442800c2b77c02c4acf
```

As you can see I'm trying to cipher the key store password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error isn't related specifically to the cipher, but due to the fact that curly braces have a special meaning within YAML. Basically, Spring (or snakeyaml) is unable to parse the YAML file (hence the `ParserException`).

To solve this particular issue, you need to wrap your property within quotes, for example:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: tdev-wssc-configserver

  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      fail-fast: true
      config:
        order: -10
      ssl:
        trust-store: file:keystore.jks
        # Add quotes
        trust-store-password: '{cipher}0b544ca0afbcd904c687d902d95b4db415f6309cbae49442800c2b77c02c4acf'
```

This is also demonstrated in [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.2.0.RELEASE/#_encryption_and_decryption), where you can see that in the `application.yml`, additional quotes are used, while in `application.properties`, these quotes aren't necessary.